# « Ce n’est pas que », introduit-elle le subjonctif dans la proposition subordonnée ?

Tags: subjonctif, subordonnées, mode-grammatical

> [*Ce n’est pas que* Pierre Gringoire **craignît** monsieur le cardinal
>   ou le **dédaignât**](https://books.google.ro/books?id=a6RAr10k_9YC&pg=PA27&lpg=PA27&dq=Ce%20n%E2%80%99est%20pas%20que%20Pierre%20Gringoire%20craign%C3%AEt%20monsieur%20le%20cardinal%20ou%20le%20d%C3%A9daign%C3%A2t.&source=bl&ots=GE1HCxOdvj&sig=CXfwdXySQ96Bh3VwpNwuiJZtrKU&hl=ro&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiyu9r1tJTTAhXKIcAKHfbWBbsQ6AEILTAB#v=onepage&q=Ce%20n%E2%80%99est%20pas%20que%20Pierre%20Gringoire%20craign%C3%AEt%20monsieur%20le%20cardinal%20ou%20le%20d%C3%A9daign%C3%A2t.&f=false).

Quelle est la règle selon laquelle les deux verbes dans ces phrases subordonnées, *craindre* et *dédaigner*, sont au subjonctif imparfait ?

Pour autant que je sache, ces deux verbes devraient être dans la proposition principale afin d'introduire une proposition dont le verbe est au subjonctif, et pas à l'inverse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd lean towards the subjunctive form of the two verbs, myself, since the expression "ce n’est pas que" can introduce ***a*** ***possibility***:

> It's not that someone {***might have done*** / ***possibly did***} something, but rather that ...

If the phrase "ce n’est pas que" were followed by "mais c'est que", I'd use the indicative form in the "c'est que" clause, as it deals with ***an (established) fact*** this time:

> Ce n’est pas que Pierre Gringoire ***craignît*** {***subjunctive***}  monsieur le cardinal ou le ***dédaignât*** {***subjunctive***} , mais (c'est) que ... {***indicative***} ...

Comment: Indeed. In fact, not only does it talk about what is merely possible instead of actual, but it goes further and suggests that it's neither possible nor real! Which is the context needed for subjunctive. As for the *proposition principale* that @user26368 wonders about, technically the *est* of *Ce n'est pas que* is the main verb.